# How to detect whether “.Net Framework 4.6.1 Hotfix” is installed on System or not using C# Code?

Tags: c#, .net, system-administration

Sometimes people install .net framework 4.6.1 and my application doesn't properly work in their environment unless they also installed the .Net Framework 4.6.1 Hotfix. So I have to sort this out explicitly on every client's machine. And also write a programm that does this check to help the people in support.

Here is the sample code which detects on client machine whether 4.6.1 or higher version is installed on client's machine but it lacks checking 4.6.1 Hotfix.
Note: 64-bit Operating System is Pre-Requisite.

```
    private static bool CheckIfVCInstalledOrNot()
    {
        bool vcInstalled = true;
        try
        {
            if (!Utilities.RedistributablePackage.IsInstalled(Utilities.RedistributablePackageVersion.VC2015to2019x64))
            {
                if (!Utilities.RedistributablePackage.IsInstalled(Utilities.RedistributablePackageVersion.VC2017x64))
                {
                    if (!Utilities.RedistributablePackage.IsInstalled(Utilities.RedistributablePackageVersion.VC2015x64))
                    {
                        if (!Utilities.RedistributablePackage.IsInstalled(Utilities.RedistributablePackageVersion.VC2013x64))
                        {
                            vcInstalled = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utilities.Logging.ErrorLog(ex);
        }
        return vcInstalled;
    }

public enum RedistributablePackageVersion
{
    VC2013x64,
    VC2015x64,
    VC2017x64,
    VC2015to2019x64
};

public static class RedistributablePackage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if a Microsoft Redistributable Package is installed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="redistributableVersion">The package version to detect.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if the package is installed, otherwise <c>false</c></returns>
    public static bool IsInstalled(RedistributablePackageVersion redistributableVersion)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (redistributableVersion)
            {
                case RedistributablePackageVersion.VC2015to2019x64:
                    var parametersVc2015to2019x64 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VC\Servicing\14.0\RuntimeMinimum", false);
                    if (parametersVc2015to2019x64 == null) return false;
                    var vc2015to2019x64Version = parametersVc2015to2019x64.GetValue("Version");
                    if (((string)vc2015to2019x64Version).StartsWith("14"))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case RedistributablePackageVersion.VC2017x64:
                    var paths2017x64 = new List<string>
                    {
                        @"Installer\Dependencies\,,amd64,14.0,bundle",
                        @"Installer\Dependencies\VC,redist.x64,amd64,14.16,bundle" //changed in 14.16.x
                    };
                    foreach (var path in paths2017x64)
                    {
                        var parametersVc2017x64 = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(path, false);
                        if (parametersVc2017x64 == null) continue;
                        var vc2017x64Version = parametersVc2017x64.GetValue("Version");
                        if (vc2017x64Version == null) return false;
                        if (((string)vc2017x64Version).StartsWith("14"))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case RedistributablePackageVersion.VC2015x64:
                    var parametersVc2015x64 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies\{d992c12e-cab2-426f-bde3-fb8c53950b0d}", false);
                    if (parametersVc2015x64 == null) return false;
                    var vc2015x64Version = parametersVc2015x64.GetValue("Version");
                    if (((string)vc2015x64Version).StartsWith("14"))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
                case RedistributablePackageVersion.VC2013x64:
                    var parametersVc2013x64 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Dependencies\{050d4fc8-5d48-4b8f-8972-47c82c46020f}", false);
                    if (parametersVc2013x64 == null) return false;
                    var vc2013x64Version = parametersVc2013x64.GetValue("Version");
                    if (((string)vc2013x64Version).StartsWith("12"))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Making certain the System is properly set up, is not really your job. You write this into the System Requirements. Maybe add a note during installation. Maybe provide the hotfix installer as part of the Setup (if you are allowed to distribute it) or pick a higher framework version sure to have the fix. And that is where your responsbiltiy ends. This a bit of a fring case, as it is about .NET Code. But at best it is a 25% your job, 75% administrator.

Comment: Honestly even providing the Hotfix as part of the Instaler might go overboard. From practice there is one Administrator rule I try to follow: Never do unrequested admin work in someone elses Adminsitration. And installing Windows/MS Patch is exactly that.

Comment: Propably off topic, but exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and you got a big issue - you are catching fatal exceptions. This is a cardinal sin of exception handling. There are two articles on the thematic I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET | I would class the absence of a specific patch as a Exogenous Exception. You should be able to throw a InvalidOperationException. Being a error very specific to your specific code is what it represents.

Comment: Sometimes they do install .net framework 4.6.1 and my application doesn't properly work in their environment and I have to sort out explicitly on every client's machine. So there is a support request from our support person and I have to write this utility for their ease.

Comment: At first I missread it a bit. I think you need to write a programm for your sides support, to diagnose the "nope, you miss that patch" problem. I rewrote the text with a proper problem description and added a tag as this falls partially into Administration.

Comment: What happens to your program if the hotfox isn't installed? Does a certain lone of code X produce exception Y, for example? Run that line of code early in the startup and catch the exception, give the user a message to check that a fix for problem Z is truly installed (link to msdn?)

Comment: I mean why should i give message on certain lines of code for some framework is not installed on your machine. It's a prerequisite and utility's job is to check all software's should be installed on that machine and support persons needs to run that utility for their ease. It's not software problem.

Comment: Do you want your software to run or not?

Comment: On a side note, please do yourself a favor and simplify `CheckIfVCInstalledOrNot`. I would recommend something along the lines of https://gist.github.com/msdeibel/c690024983d10356322b21e7f1c17d0e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the registry DWORD value of the hotfix and query the registry for that value.

Now if you nee the  [hotfix 3154529](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3154529/hotfix-rollup-3154529-for-the-net-framework-4-6-and-4-6-1-in-windows) you can see that the registry value is "394297".

So to find out you can see from this [Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed?redirectedfrom=MSDN#net_d) that the value for .net framework 4.6.1 is larger or equal to 393295 and 4.6.1 with hotfix should be 394297 or larger (newer hotfix or servicepack applied).

Comment: Already found the solution but this may be helpful for others. We required Hotfix registry DWORD "394294" in which they resolved click once TLS issue.